# Generate image with PHP using 0 with a slash through it

Tags: php, fonts, opentype

I'm trying to generate an image with PHP using functions like:
`imagecreatefrompng`, `imagettfbbox`, `imagettftext`

All good, I'm able to generate the image. One issue that I have is that need the following sentence:

`Hi. 0 is a nice number.`

I need that `0` to be with a slash through it. Pretty much like the `0` on the top right of this image.

[image]

An alternative would be to edit the font I guess.

Comment: It would help if you say which font you're even using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pretty much nailed the answer in your question.
You just need to use a font that has the 0 with the line in (or modify a font file if inclined) - then you'll be all good.

Comment: True. I modified the font after all and changed the 0.

Comment: Or... make sure to use the correct opentype feature, if there are `alt` forms for the 0 glyph? Why edit a font that already has what you need, after all.